# How do I raise underlining within underlining?

Tags: underline

I'm recreating some mathematical notation from chapter 1 of Modern Classical Physics by Thorne and Blandford. I have a command `\slot` that creates a blank, underlined "slot" and that slot can itself contain exactly one additional "slot," drawn by the `\smallslot` command. The problem I need for the inner slot to be raised slightly above the outer slot. At present, as you can see below, the two "slots" overlap. I think the problem is that when `\smallslot` is used inside of `\slot` it too gets `\smash`ed, which removes all of the vertical space, but that doesn't make complete sense to me due to the presence of the `\mbox`. How can I slightly raise the height of the inner "slot?" There will never be more than one inner and one outer "slot."

Here is my original MWE and its output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\slot}{ s O{~} }{%
  \IfBooleanTF {#1} % check for *
    {% * doesn't print a filled slot.
      %\,\smash{\makebox[1.5em]{\ensuremath{#2}}}\,
      {\ensuremath{#2}}
    }%
    {% Print a filled slot by default, a la Thorne and Blandford.
      \,\underline{\smash{\makebox[1.5em]{\ensuremath{#2}}}}\,
    }%
}%

\newcommand*{\smallslot}{\,\underline{\smash{\makebox[0.04em]{\ensuremath{~}}}}\,}

\begin{document}

\[
  \mathbf{a}(\slot) \qquad 
  %\mathbf{a}(\slot[\mathbf{b}]) \qquad 
  %\mathbf{a}(\slot[\mathbf{b}(\slot)]) \qquad 
  \mathbf{a}(\slot[\mathbf{b}(\smallslot)]) \qquad 
  %\mathbf{a}(\mathbf{b})
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Original compiled MWE results]

EDIT: Per Donald Arseneau's suggestion, I removed `\smash` and here is the resulting MWE and its output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\slot}{ s O{} }{%
  \IfBooleanTF {#1} % check for *
    {% * doesn't print a filled slot.
      %\,\smash{\makebox[1.5em]{\ensuremath{#2}}}\,
      {\,\makebox[2.0em]{\ensuremath{#2}}\,}
    }%
    {% Print a filled slot by default, a la Thorne and Blandford.
      %\,\underline{\smash{\makebox[1.5em]{\ensuremath{#2}}}}\,
      \,\underline{\makebox[2.0em]{\ensuremath{#2}}}\,
    }%
}%

%\newcommand*{\smallslot}{\,\underline{\smash{\makebox[0.04em]{\ensuremath{~}}}}\,}
\newcommand*{\smallslot}{\,\underline{\makebox[0.80em]{\ensuremath{}}}\,}

\begin{document}
\[
  \mathbf{a}(\slot) \qquad 
  %\mathbf{a}(\slot[\mathbf{b}]) \qquad 
  %\mathbf{a}(\slot[\mathbf{b}(\slot)]) \qquad % Without the smaller slot.
  \mathbf{a}(\slot[\mathbf{b}(\smallslot)]) \qquad 
  %\mathbf{a}(\mathbf{b})
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Modified compiled output]

I suspect the answer is going to be "no," but my new question is whether there is a way to make the outer slot's underline stay at the same height while the inner slot's underline is raised. As you can see, the exact opposite seems to now happen.

Comment: It is the \smash that prevents \underline from being "under" its argument.

Comment: Aha! Okay I will attempt to fix that. Thank you very much.

Comment: @DonaldArseneau That basically fixed the problem, but also raised an additional need for clarification. See edited question.

Comment: Since you have different commands `\smallslot` versus `\slot`, it is in principle easy, but (a) why have separet commands?, and (b) you probably want the innermost "slot" to be at the baseline, and definitely *NOT* rased or lower any characters.

Comment: Inner raise... as in the answer by @Cicada which raises characters? Or do you want the inner \slot to be raised to cross over characters? Or do you want only the empty slot to be raised?

Comment: @DonaldArseneau There are two commands because the outer slots must all be the same width and vertical position regardless of whether or not they're filled. In order to do that, I must make the inner slot narrower. The inner slot will never have anything inside it besides the blank because in this notation, a slot within a slot makes the slots "cancel" and go away. So the second example would simply reduce to `\mathbf{a}(\mathbf{b})`. It seems the inner slot should indeed be raised a bit over the outer slot, which I think should be at the baseline. I hope I articulated that correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manual adjustment with `raisebox` may help:

[image: raisebox]

Glyph depth (here, the bottom part of the `(` and `)`) shifts the underline down.

What does the expected output look like, in Chapter 1?

Using the "dummy text" method, with and without (), gives:

[image: brackets]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\slot}{ s O{} }{%
  \IfBooleanTF {#1} % check for *
    {% * doesn't print a filled slot.
      %\,\smash{\makebox[1.5em]{\ensuremath{#2}}}\,
      {\,\makebox[2.0em]{\ensuremath{#2}}\,}
    }%
    {% Print a filled slot by default, a la Thorne and Blandford.
      %\,\underline{\smash{\makebox[1.5em]{\ensuremath{#2}}}}\,
      \,\underline{\makebox[2.0em]{\ensuremath{#2}}}\,
    }%
}%

\newcommand*{\smallslot}{\,\underline{\makebox[0.80em][1ex]{\ensuremath{x}}}\,}

\begin{document}
\[
  \mathbf{a}(\slot) \qquad 
  \mathbf{a}(\slot[\raisebox{2.1pt}{$\mathbf{b}$(\smallslot)}]) \qquad 
\]
\end{document}
```

MWE variant

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newsavebox{\slotboxname}
\begin{lrbox}{\slotboxname}{\textcolor{white}{(xxx}}\end{lrbox}%

\newsavebox{\slotboxnameb}
\begin{lrbox}{\slotboxnameb}{\textcolor{white}{(xx}}\end{lrbox}%

\newsavebox{\slotboxnamec}
\begin{lrbox}{\slotboxnamec}{\textcolor{white}{xxx}}\end{lrbox}%

\newsavebox{\slotboxnamed}
\begin{lrbox}{\slotboxnamed}{\textcolor{white}{xx}}\end{lrbox}%




\begin{document}

\[
a(\underline{\usebox{\slotboxname}}) = a(\underline{\raisebox{2pt}{b(\underline{\usebox{\slotboxnameb}})}})
\]

\[
a(\underline{\usebox{\slotboxnamec}}) = a(\underline{\raisebox{2pt}{b(\underline{\usebox{\slotboxnamed}})}})
\]


\end{document}
```

Actually, using `\phantom{}` would be more suitable than white text on white background, which latter is just to experimentally show that not all spaces are empty.

Acknowledgement: About `lrbox`es: One thing leads to another -- A question about `quotchap` ([Place quote and chapter heading on separate pages with quotechap package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557722/place-quote-and-chapter-heading-on-separate-pages-with-quotechap-package/557813#557813)) led to having a look in the `.sty` file.

Comment: Thank you very much. Let me study this to make sure I completely understand it.