# Place quote and chapter heading on separate pages with quotechap package

Tags: spacing, formatting, chapters

I am trying to use the `quotchap` package, but I want the quote and chapter heading on separate pages. That is, for one chapter, I want a full-page quote, followed by the standard chapter heading on the following page.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{quotchap}

\begin{document}
\begin{savequote}[45mm]
---When shall we three meet again
in thunder, lightning, or in rain?
---When the hurlyburly’s done,
when the battle’s lost and won.
\qauthor{Shakespeare, Macbeth}
\end{savequote}

% I want a page break here! But \newpage or \clearpage do not work

\chapter{Classic Sesame Street}
Some chapter text. 

\end{document}
```

Is this possible? I will want to revert back to the standard formatting for subsequent chapters.

Comment: Please make your example compilable. There is no document class, and textit needs braces around its argument

Comment: Thanks @daleif, updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `epigraph` package:

```
% quotchapprob.tex  SE 557722
\documentclass{book}
%\documentclass{memoir} memoir and quotchap don't work together

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{quotchap}

\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}
\begin{comment}
\begin{savequote}[45mm]
---When shall we three meet again
in thunder, lightning, or in rain?
---When the hurlyburly’s done,
when the battle’s lost and won.
\qauthor{Shakespeare, Macbeth}
\end{savequote}
% I want a page break here! But \newpage or \clearpage do not work
\end{comment}

\mbox{} \thispagestyle{empty} \clearpage  % empty first page and go to second page
\renewcommand{\epigraphflush}{flushleft} % put epigraph at left of page
\epigraph{%
---When shall we three meet again
in thunder, lightning, or in rain?
---When the hurlyburly’s done,
when the battle’s lost and won.}{%
Shakespeare, Macbeth}

\chapter{Classic Sesame Street}
Some chapter text. 

\chapter{Another Road}
Text.

\end{document}
```

The above is a modified version of your MWE, for which thank you. You can use the `\epigraph` command to place an epigraph wherever you want it, plus adjusting the size, fonts, etc. See the manual (via `texdoc epigraph`). The preliminary fiddling is to make sure that your epigraph will be on the verso (left hand) page facing the chapter title on the recto (right hand) page. The page fiddling would have been much easier with the `memoir` class (a superset of `book`) but unfortunately `memoir` and `quotchap` don't work together.